# Simplest example from pfgplots documentation not working

Tags: errors, pgfplots

I get a lot of errors when I try to compile even the simplest examples with `pgfplots`.
The following is taken from the documentation of the package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel=Cost,
      ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
      (2,-2.8559703)
      (3,-3.5301677)
      (4,-4.3050655)
      (5,-5.1413136)
      (6,-6.0322865)
      (7,-6.9675052)
      (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get more than 30 errors of the following type:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmathresult.
<to be read again>
                  1
l.11       ylabel=Error]

You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

Strangely, the produced pdf output contains the (visually) correct plot.

I'm using TeXLive 2009, pdfTeX, pgfplots 1.5.1, pgf 2.00.

edit: I believe that this has something to do with my system (missing or old packages?) but I'm not sure. Maybe someone has seen this before?

Comment: If I remove `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}` it compiles without problems for me. I am using `pgf v2.10` though.

Comment: I get exactly the same output if I remove this line.

Comment: Then I would advise you to update to `pgf v2.10`. Also, register on this site and get a proper username.

Comment: Updating to pgf v2.10 ideed helped - thanks! I already was registered but now changed my name.

Comment: @wh1t3: Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was determined in the comments the problem is with the version of `pgf` you are using. Update to `pgf v2.10` to resolve the issue.

Comment: I wasn't allowed to write an answer to my own question since I'm a newbie - thanks for your help.

Comment: @boothby81 if it answers your question consider accepting the answer so the question is listed as answered. You can do so by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.